# Trying to produce monospaced output in pyqt browser

Tags: python, pyqt, sympy

I have modified a short piece of pyqt code to produce real-time rendering of a user's expression. I have used sympy's pretty-printing function for this, however the output does not appear correctly as the QTextBrowser uses a proportional rather than a monospaced font.

As a beginner I would also welcome any other thoughts you had on the code.

Many thanks and best wishes,
Geddes

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import sympy
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QLineEdit("please type an expression")
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("textChanged (const QString&)"),self.updateUi)

    def updateUi(self):
        text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
        for z in range(0,9):
            text = text.replace('x'+str(z),'x^'+str(z))
            text = text.replace(')'+str(z),')^'+str(z))
            text = text.replace(str(z)+'x',str(z)+'*x')
            text = text.replace(str(z)+'(',str(z)+'*(')
        try:
            self.browser.append(sympy.printing.pretty(sympy.sympify(text)))
            self.browser.clear()
            self.browser.append(sympy.printing.pretty(sympy.sympify(text)))
        except:
            if text=='': self.browser.clear()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change the font with [`setFontFamily`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtextedit.html#setFontFamily).

Concerning your code: I haven't really worked with PyQt yet (only some hacks like the font family in qbzr...), so I can't tell you if everything is okay. But the following is not a good idea:

```
    except:
        if text=='': self.browser.clear()
```

1. Never catch all exceptions with `except:`. This will also catch [`BaseException`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html)s like `SystemExit`, which shouldn't be caught unless you have a reason to do so. Always catch specific exceptions, or if you're at the highest level (before the unhandled exception handler is executed) and want to log errors, rather use `except Exception:` which will only handle exceptions based on `Exception`.
2. `if text==''` - I think `if not text` is more "pythonic".

Comment: Good catch on `setFontFamily`, I was about to edit my answer to that since I ran across that in the docs after `setCurrentFont`.  I'll leave mine as `setCurrentFont` for variety in opinions, and also in case he wants to set font size or something else :)

Comment: @Benn: `setCurrentFont` makes sense if you want to set the same font object on multiple widgets. For single widgets, `setFontFamily` is a good option. Both are correct ;)

Comment: Great advice on the exception - I was wondering how to log errors! Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

QTextBrowser inherits QTextEdit, so you can use the [`setCurrentFont(QFont)`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtextedit.html#setCurrentFont) method to set a monospace font.

```
self.browser = QTextBrowser()
self.browser.setCurrentFont(QFont("Courier New")) #Or whatever monospace font family you want...
```

As for general comments on style, there's probably a way do change your text replacement stuff in `updateUi()` to regex, but I can't be sure without seeing sample data to figure out what you're trying to do.

Also, you should probably refactor

```
try:
    self.browser.append(sympy.printing.pretty(sympy.sympify(text)))
    self.browser.clear()
    self.browser.append(sympy.printing.pretty(sympy.sympify(text)))
except:
    if text=='': self.browser.clear()
```

Into something more like:

```
self.browser.clear()
try:
    self.browser.append(sympy.printing.pretty(sympy.sympify(text)))
except:
    if text=='': self.browser.clear()
```

Except probably catching the actual Exception you're expecting.

**EDIT**
Here's something for the equation normalizing it looks like you're trying to do, it works with lowercase a-z and real numbers:

```
def updateUi(self):
    text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
    text = re.sub(r'(\d+)([\(]|[a-z])',r'\1*\2',text) #for multiplication
    text = re.sub(r'([a-z]|[\)])(\d+)',r'\1^\2',text) #for exponentiation
```

The first pattern looks for 1 or more digits `\d+` followed by an open parenthesis, or a single letter a-z `[\(]|[a-z]`.  It uses parentheses to capture the digit part of the pattern and the variable part of the pattern, and inserts a * between them. `\1*\2`.

The second pattern looks for a variable a-z or a close parenthesis `[a-z]|[\)]`, followed by one or more digits `\d+`.  It uses the grouping parentheses to capture the digit and the variable again, and inserts a ^ between them `\1^\2`.

It's not quite perfect (doesn't handle `xy --> x*y`) but its closer.  If you want to make a full computer algebra system you'll probably need to build a dedicated parser :)

Comment: The setCurrentFont works perfectly! My text replacement is to change 3x into 3*x or x2 into x^2 etc. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Geddes - see my edit for some regex for equation normalization.  It works for the few complex inputs I tossed at it (the scariest being `3(a2+b)2 + 2x5+ 4(c+d)3` --> `3*(a^2+b)^2 + 2*x^5+ 4*(c+d)^3`

Comment: thanks again, I would never have thought of doing it that way!